# Open a project file directy on the Browser with Vite

Tags: vite

I use Vite to run my React App but I want it to open directly on the browser without me having to click on the link appearing in the terminal when typing npm run dev.

do you know how to leverage my vite config file to do that?

I did some googling, looked into the Vite documentation and found

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    open: '/docs/index.html',
  },
})
```

I copied and pasted the server object inside of my define config but it did not work and rendered a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Almost there- you need to pass `true` to `server.open`

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    open: true
  }
})
```